# Are non-Google emails stored only locally when using the Gmail app?

Tags: security, gmail, google, privacy

The [Gmail app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gm) allows to add non-Google email provides (via POP and IMAP).

Is it mentioned somewhere that the emails pulled from these providers stay on the device and are not stored/shared with Google?

*Note: I have marked my own question as duplicate (and not deleted it) because there is another one which is strikingly similar, but the answer is purely speculative.*

Comment: If they are not stored on the server, how do you think things like drafts, important mails, old mails, search etc are done? To my mind, they have to be stored

Comment: Search especially is a good example. Long time back Gmail app would ask you how many days of mails to store. Note it doesn't now. But you can search your non Gmail mails. How is it possible if they are not stored unless I am missing something?

Comment: @beeshyams: the storing part can be done locally but, indeed, the search is more complicated (it could be local but that would require a brand new implementation "on premises" (of the phone). I do not use gmail for non-Google emails (yet) so I do not know how the search works (and whether it is similar / as-fast-as the gmail one)

Comment: I used it long back but don't recall details of how fast it was

Comment: I just tested searching a new email on my Yahoo! through Gmail for Android, and it found the email even before the account has been synced, and thus my only guess for now is that the app searches *and syncs* at the same time (still stored locally). On the other hand, there is [Gmailify](https://www.blog.google/products/gmail/gmailify-best-of-gmail-without-gmail/) that *links* non-Google emails to Gmail, though I haven't tested the feature.